# Sequelize not returning instance of model

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

The sequelize documentation (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/raw-queries/) states:

> If you pass a model the returned data will be instances of that model.

```
// Callee is the model definition. This allows you to easily map a query to a predefined model
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects', { model: Projects }).then(function(projects){
  // Each record will now be a instance of Project
})
```

I have defined a model for a resource called `agent`.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
   let Agent = sequelize.define('Agent', {
      responseStatus: DataTypes.STRING,
      agentnum: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        field : 'agentno'
      },
      fname :  {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
        field: 'fname'
      },
      lname : {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field : 'lname'
      }, 
      fullname : {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
        field: 'full_name'
      }, 
      status : {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'business_status'
      }, 
      loginDate: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
      freezeTableName: false,
      timestamps: false
  });

  return Agent;
};
```

And when calling `sequelize.query` with my query and specifying model:Agent, I get an error thrown from sequelize:

`TypeError: this.model.bulkBuild is not a function`

the stack points to `sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query.js:675`.

This error persists **until** I apply a QueryType of `sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW`. At this point the query completes and I get a JSON response but it is not an instance of my Agent model. The JSON response from the sequelize query contains field names that should be mapped to.

I have imported my model (its just one) according to the directions found in their express sample (https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js). The models collection shows that my Agent model is included.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import config from './config';

export default callback => {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config.params);

  sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    let db = { }

    let agentModel = sequelize.import('model/agent.js');
    db[agentModel.name] = agentModel;

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

    db.sequelize.authenticate().then(function() {
      console.log('CONNECTION OK');
    });


    callback(db);

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('FAILED TO CONNECT: ', err.message);
  });
}
```

I want the query to return an instance of Agent when that query is run (invoked from a POST to my api). I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT 1/30** Here is the code generating the sequelize object, and passing in the model. The model collection shows my item is added, but it has no properties.

```
connectDb: (function () {
        var sequelize;
        function createInstance() {
            var sequelizeInstance, connectedAndAuthenticated;
            sequelizeInstance = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config.params);
            connectedAndAuthenticated = sequelizeInstance.authenticate();
            connectedAndAuthenticated.sequelize = sequelizeInstance;
            connectedAndAuthenticated.Sequelize = Sequelize;

            var model = sequelizeInstance.import('../src/model/agent.js');


            return connectedAndAuthenticated;
        }
        return {
            getInstance : function () {
                if (!sequelize) {
                    sequelize = createInstance();
                }
                return sequelize;
            }
        };
    }())
```

**EDIT 1/26** After manipulating the `QueryTypes`, I discovered two things - that I inadvertently created a table in the database with the name of the model (Agent), and that the object returned has a `tablename` property value of empty. The `schema` and `tablename` are specified by me, but the query, being a stored procedure that joins a number of queries and tables, does not directly map to an object in my database named `Agent`. That being said, the documentation to me seems to suggest that **this does not and should not matter**, as I am creating my own model that is bound to the query result.

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: `db.sequelize
        .query(
          "DECLARE @response VARCHAR(256); EXEC API_Login @agentnum = N'" + agentNum + "', @hashedPassword = '" + password + "', @response = @response OUTPUT; SELECT @response AS N'response'",{ model: Agent, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW})
          .spread(function(Agent) { 
              res.status(200).json(Agent); 
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
             handleError(err, res);
          });` - It's a stored procedure being invoked.

Comment: what if you do `type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT` ?

Comment: @Adam every other QueryType either fails or returns nothing in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a simple typo. I don't think `Agent` is actually defined in your scope. I think you should be passing `agentModel` or whatever you bound the import to.

```
let agentModel = sequelize.import('model/agent.js');    
db.sequelize.query( "DECLARE @response VARCHAR(256); EXEC API_Login @agentnum = N'" + agentNum + "', @hashedPassword = '" + password + "', @response = @response OUTPUT; SELECT @response AS N'response'",{ model: agentModel, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW}) .spread(function(Agent) { res.status(200).json(Agent); }) .catch(function(err) { handleError(err, res); });
```

Note I'm using `{model: agentModel, ...}` not `{model: Agent, ...}` because `Agent` is undefined outside of the callback.

Your error `TypeError: this.model.bulkBuild is not a function` makes perfect sense if `Agent` is not actually a model but something else (or undefined).

**UPDATE**

You mention in comments on the post below that: "I have synced the model - the query attempts to create a table, instead of binding to the passed in agent model" and "It should not be creating a table".

Why do you think that is that is the case? Creating the table during sync() is *normal behaviour* for Sequelize.

I think you misunderstand how Sequelize works. It creates a table for every registered model during sync. If it can't create that table it might be returning an invalid model and that is why you are getting errors.

Models are explicity tied to individual database tables, that's the fundamental behavior of Sequelize. Each model instance represents a row of that table. If you are working with stored proceedures then you are probably better off using using the native database library and defining your own abstraction layer.

I'm sure you can disable and/or override all the default synchronization between the model and the underlying DB table but at a certain point or complexity you'd have basically just written your own abstraction library and it would be cleaner to just do it from scratch.

Maybe you can use Sequelize the way you want but at the very least you should not be calling `sync()`. What side-effects that leads to I can't say but I can say that unless you define your own `beforeSync` hook `sync()` will always create a table in your schema:

```
Model.prototype.sync = function(options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.hooks = options.hooks === undefined ? true : !!options.hooks;
  options = Utils._.extend({}, this.options, options);

  var self = this
    , attributes = this.tableAttributes;

  return Promise.try(function () {
    if (options.hooks) {
      return self.runHooks('beforeSync', options);
    }
  }).then(function () {
    if (options.force) {
      return self.drop(options);
    }
  }).then(function () {
    return self.QueryInterface.createTable(self.getTableName(options), attributes, options, self);
  })
  ...
  }).return(this);
};
```

Comment: The error still persists. I should have clarified that I did try this before. At first I understood this to be the name of the model in the collection (it is defined as 'Agent' so I thought the JSON wanted the name of the defined model, not the instance), but when I changed it I get the same exception on every other query type except Raw, which returns raw json.

Comment: Have you tried console.debug(agentModel) to see what it actually is? Does it have a bulkBuild method? Also if the library really wants the _name_ of the agent (and I'm not convinced it does), then that would be the string `"Agent"` rather than the variable `Agent` (which is presumably undefined)

Comment: Yes. It is a JSON object that looks like this: `{ Agent : Agent }`. No properties are assigned to it. It is loading the model file, because if I intentionally get the path wrong the app throws an exception, but otherwise that's all I've noticed about this.

Comment: I get what you are saying, yet the documentation that I originally cited seems to indicate that if I wanted to bind a query to an already existing model that I could do so by applying the model to it. In this case, I expected the query fields to map to the fieldnames I indicated, and that's not happening. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435291/sequelize-mapping-between-raw-data-and-model where another SO member experienced a similar issue (no solution is posted there)

Comment: That doesn't clarify my main question though. Do you know what `Agent` really is? How is the variable `Agent` being defined in the scope where the query is being run? In the code you've posted `Agent` is `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

sequelize doc is confusing .i'm explaining you clean way to use sequelize
put

```
var models = require('../models');
```

in your code file be sure models directory contain index.js as you told me in your question and also Project model. **be careful, other then correctly configured model there must not anything.**
Now put

```
 models.sequelize.query("select 1 as val").then(function(result){
console.log(result)
})
```

in your code 
to check connection also you should use find query like

```
 models.Projects.findAll().then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
    })
```

Comment: Yep, its confusing! But this is not an acceptable answer. I am able to connect to the existing SQL Server instance, and I am able to query against it. What I cannot seem to figure out or do is bind my existing model (which is in the models directory) to the output of a stored procedure, even though the documentation seems to suggest that this is possible by passing in the name of your model.

Comment: data is automatically bind with model calling with model name. i'm not getting what are you confusing. but i think you are looking for class, getter & setter method to manipulate data when store or retrieve

Comment: "data is automatically bind with model calling with model name" - what I am saying is that I have done this. I have tried both adding the model to the models collection manually as well as specifying the model in the query but it does not automatically bind. The model is loaded when I check the collection. Instead it returns just the query result. This isnt a find - the idea as I read it in the documentation is you simply define your model and when you query it will bind to the provided model. It doesnt do this right now. Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: The `index.js` file in the models directory appears to be a loader. I am attempting to load the model when I create my database object.It's just one model. I can see that it is added to the collection if I log the object contents to the console (it outputs the object name). But it has no properties. See updated code above.

Comment: To add, I have synced the model - the query attempts to create a table, instead of binding to the passed in agent model. I know this because an exception is thrown in the console when I execute this test: 'Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'Agents'.' It should not be creating a table - this is a stored procedure performing a SELECT

Comment: To add again - I have reduced this to a parameterized SELECT statement and get the same result as before "this.model.builBuild is not a function"